# How to store one variable from multiple return variable from call function in List compression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want outputs like `output` from following code function:

```
def addMulDiv(i, k):
    add=k+i
    mul=k*i
    div=k//2
    return add, mul, div

Lst = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    add, _, _ = addMulDiv(i, 500)
    Lst.append(add)
    
print(Lst)
```

> output: [501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509]

But I am trying with following `code` in List compression but I failed.

```
Lst = [add for i in range(1, 10) add, _, _ = addMulDiv(i, 500)]
```

How can I do this easily?

Thanks.

Comment: ```Lst2 = [addMulDiv(i,500)[0] for i in range(1,10)]```??

Comment: ``[addMulDiv(i, 500)[0] for i in range(1, 10)]`` would do, but there really isn't anything wrong about using a regular loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `addMulDiv()` returns a tuple, so you can just use

```
Lst = [addMulDiv(i, 500)[0] for i in range(1, 10)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is actually returning a tuple. Hence, you can fetch the first element using `[0]`

```
Lst1 = [addMulDiv(i,500)[0] for i in range(1,10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't fully understood how List compressions works.
For instance,

```
[i ** 2 for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]
```

This means that you get only even numbers from range and raise it to the power of 2.

```
output : [4, 16, 36, 64]
```

Solution for your problem:

```
def addMulDiv(i, k):
    add = k + i
    mul = k * i
    div = k // 2
    return add, mul, div


Lst = [addMulDiv(i, 500)[0] for i in range(1, 10)]
print(Lst)
```

This means that you get only add result from you function return, because add result has 0 index in returned tuple